# SQL Statement includes IF EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem about an sql statement in my project. The code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM person_drug WHERE drug_id=3 AND person_id=1)
BEGIN
   UPDATE person_drug SET amount=3 WHERE drug_id=3 AND person_id=1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO person_drug VALUES (1,3,3)
END
```

When i run it i got:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax error.

But when i run `UPDATE,SELECT,INSERT` statement above seperately i got no error. 
What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is this being run inside a stored procedure or function?  The `IF/ELSE` flow control constructs cannot be executed outside that context in MySQL.

Comment: Remove the `BEGIN` and `END` keywords *inside* the `IF` and `ELSE` blocks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's flow control statements (`IF/ELSE/WHILE`) can only be used in context of a stored procedure or function. They do not work in interactive queries.

The best solution is to make use of proper indexing and uniqueness constraints.

If you have a primary key or unique index defined across `(drug_id, person_id)`, then you may [use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and perform this entire action in one statement:

```
/* key ensures uniqueness for drug_id, person_id */
ALTER TABLE person_drug ADD UNIQUE KEY (drug_id, person_id);

/* Then it's possible to use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE */
INSERT INTO person_drug (drug_id, person_id, amount) 
  VALUES (3, 1, 3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = VALUES(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BEGIN
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM person_drug WHERE drug_id=3 AND person_id=1)
       UPDATE person_drug SET amount=3 WHERE drug_id=3 AND person_id=1
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO person_drug VALUES (1,3,3)
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

if u r making a stored procedure means u can do it like this:

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE person

AS
BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;



IF EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM person_drug WHERE drug_id=3 AND person_id=1)
```

BEGIN
   UPDATE person_drug SET amount=3 WHERE drug_id=3 AND person_id=1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO person_drug VALUES (1,3,3)

END
end
GO